# Storing these vectors but which data structure to use in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Each iteration of the following loop generates a vector of dimension 50x1
Id like to store all the vectors from the loop collectively in a single data structure.

```
  def get_y_hat(y_bar, x_train, theta_Ridge_Matrix):
     print theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape
     print theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape[0]
     for i in range(theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape[0]):
        yH = np.dot(x_train, theta_Ridge_Matrix[i].T)
        print yH
```

Which data structure should I use? Im new to Python but based on what Ive researched online there are 2 options: numpy array and list of lists

I will need to access each vector of 50 elements later outside this method. There could be 200 to 500 vectors I will be storing.

Could someone give me sample code of such a data structure as well

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason not to be using a 2D numpy array?

Comment: Yes I would like to but,How would I append the yH value to a 2D array?

Comment: In this case, storing a list of 1D numpy arrays is probably your best solution. Storing a list of lists will quickly become excessively memory hungry, and appending to a numpy array is inefficient.  Often when building up a numpy array from an unknown number of smaller arrays, it's easiest (and fastest) to store the smaller arrays as a list and then stack them together at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest using numpy for that you need to install it

On windows from this site :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/

some example how you can use it .

```
import numpy as np
```

we will create an array , we name it mat

```
>>> mat = np.random.randn(2,3)
>>> mat
array([[ 1.02063865, 1.52885147, 0.45588211],
       [-0.82198131, 0.20995583, 0.31997462]])
```

The array is transposed using verb 'T'

```
>>> mat.T
array([[ 1.02063865, -0.82198131],
       [ 1.52885147, 0.20995583],
       [ 0.45588211, 0.31997462]])
```

The shape of any array is changed by using the \verb"reshape" method

```
>>> mat = np.random.randn(3,6)
array([[ 2.01139326, 1.33267072, 1.2947112 , 0.07492725, 0.49765694,
         0.01757505],
       [ 0.42309629, 0.95921276, 0.55840131, -1.22253606, -0.91811118,
         0.59646987],
       [ 0.19714104, -1.59446001, 1.43990671, -0.98266887, -0.42292461,
        -1.2378431 ]])
>>> mat.reshape(2,9)
array([[ 2.01139326, 1.33267072, 1.2947112 , 0.07492725, 0.49765694,
         0.01757505, 0.42309629, 0.95921276, 0.55840131],
       [-1.22253606, -0.91811118, 0.59646987, 0.19714104, -1.59446001,
         1.43990671, -0.98266887, -0.42292461, -1.2378431 ]])
```

We can change the shape of variable using the \verb"shape" attributes.

```
>>> mat = np.random.randn(4,3)
>>> mat.shape
(4, 3)
>>> mat
array([[-1.47446507, -0.46316836, 0.44047531],
       [-0.21275495, -1.16089705, -1.14349478],
       [-0.83299338, 0.20336677, 0.13460515],
       [-1.73323076, -0.66500491, 1.13514327]])
>>> mat.shape = 2,6
>>> mat.shape
(2, 6)

>>> mat
array([[-1.47446507, -0.46316836, 0.44047531, -0.21275495, -1.16089705,
        -1.14349478],
       [-0.83299338, 0.20336677, 0.13460515, -1.73323076, -0.66500491,
         1.13514327]])
```

Comment: Don't confuse numpy arrays with numpy matrices

Comment: thanks for feedback Benjamin . you are right. it is an array not a matrix , i modulate the word , and you can edit or modulate it if you feel and correct the mistakes ,thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think storing the data from your loop in a `dict` and than convert it to a [`pandas.Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) (which are build on top of numpy arrays) should be an efficient solution, allowing you to further process your data as a whole or as single vectors.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {}
# this would be your loop
for i in range(50):
    data['run_%02d' % i] = np.random.randn(50)
data = pd.DataFrame(data) # sorted keys of the dict will be the columns
```

You can access single vectors as attribute or via the key:

```
print data['run_42'].describe() # or data.run_42.describe()

count    50.000000
mean      0.021426
std       1.027607
min      -2.472225
25%      -0.601868
50%       0.014949
75%       0.641488
max       2.391289
```

or further analyse the whole data:

```
print data.mean()

run_00   -0.015224
run_01   -0.006971
..
run_48   -0.115935
run_49    0.147738
```

or have a look at your data using `matplotlib` (as you are tagging your question with `matplotlib`):

```
data.boxplot(rot=90) 
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example_boxplot]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on a numpy array as I haven't used one before, but for using a list of lists Python already has built in support.

For example to do so:

```
AList = [1, 2, 3]
BList = [4, 5, 6]
CList = [7, 8, 9]
List_of_Lists = []

List_of_Lists.append(AList)
List_of_Lists.append(BList)
List_of_Lists.append(CList)

print(List_of_Lists)
```

which would yeild:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

There are also others ways you can go about creating the lists instead of intializing them all from the start for instance:

```
ListCreator = int(input('Input how many lists are needed: '))
ListofLists = [[] for index in range(ListCreator)]
```

There are more ways to go about it but I don't know how you plan on implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
import numpy as np

def get_y_hat(y_bar, x_train, theta_Ridge_Matrix):
     print theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape
     print theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape[0]
     yH = np.empty(theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape[0], theta_Ridge_Matrix[0].shape[0])
     for i in range(theta_Ridge_Matrix.shape[0]):
        yH[i, :] = np.dot(x_train, theta_Ridge_Matrix[i].T)
     print yH
```

if you store the `theta_Ridge_Matrix` in a 3D array, you can also let `np.dot` do the work by using `yH = np.dot(x_train, theta_Ridge_Matrix)`, which would sum over the second last dimension of the matrix.